# Node JS -- separator

Tags: node.js, command-line

I'm reading a [tutorial](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/unit-test-node-code-in-10-seconds/) on getting started with Node.js unit tests:

We set up our tests to run on file changes by adding the following the the `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "mocha -R spec test/*-spec.js",
  "watch": "npm test -- --watch"
}
```

There is a note:

> passing command line options using -- separator requires Node > 0.11

What is the `--` separator?

Is it a switch? A flag? Is a standard for Node.js command line apps? Where can I read more about it?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean-also-known-as-bare-double-dash. In this case, it’s separating npm flags from extra arguments to the test script.

Comment: So in this context `npm` is the executable, `test` a subcommand which is running another script `mocha -R spec test/*-spec.js`. The `--watch` switch is meant for the other script (and so we're "done" giving it arguments/options) so we give the `--` separator which lets us pass the `--watch` switch to the other script?

Comment: Precisely right! That would make a good self-answer.

Comment: @Ryan would appreciate you taking a look and letting me know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading [another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11382/173557):

> A double dash `--` is used in bash built-in commands and many other commands to signify the end of command options

So in this context:

- `npm` is the executable
- `test` a subcommand which is running another script `mocha -R spec test/*-spec.js`
- `--watch` is a switch is meant for the other script
- because we're "done" giving `npm` arguments and options we give the `--` separator which lets us pass the `--watch` switch to the other script